# Docker Containers' Network Access Configuration

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile, keycloak

I'm struggling to configure docker-compose file in order to achieve below structure. Web container needs to be accessible through virtual pcs, physical devices (local & external), but the Keycloak container needs to be only accessible by web container. How can I achieve this?

[Desired Network Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzVE.png)

Web Container starts flask app expose on port 5000.

My docker-compose file currently:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
```

Comment: If you remove the `ports:` block from the `keycloak` container, it mostly won't be accessible from outside Docker.  Is that enough for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah, but how can web container access it? in web container, it sends requests to keycloak:8080 api. will it breaks these requests?

Comment: Connections between containers don't require `ports:`, and ignore them if they're present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a container doesn't have `ports:`, it (mostly*) isn't accessible from outside of Docker.  If your goal is to have the container only be accessible from other containers, you can just delete `ports:`.

In comments you ask about the container being reachable from other containers.  So long as both containers are on the same Docker network (or the same Compose-provided `default` network) they can communicate using the other container's Compose service name and the port the process inside the container is listening on.  `ports:` aren't required, and they're ignored if they're present.

So in your setup, it should be enough to remove the `ports:` from the `keycloak` container.

```yaml
version: '2.4'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
    # can call keycloak:8080
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    environment: { ... }
    # no ports:, container_name: is also unnecessary
```

(*) On a native-Linux host, the container's Docker-internal IP address will be reachable from the same host, but not other hosts, if you have some way of finding it (including port-scanning 172.16.0.0/20).  If someone can run `docker` commands then they can also easily attach other containers to the same network and gain access to the container, but if they can run `docker` commands then they can also pretty straightforwardly root the entire host.